# Getting an error for finding minimum value in a file after finding maximum

Tags: file, python-3.x, loops

So I am having an issue with the function returning an error:

"builtins.ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence"

I was able to find the max and minumum values when taking the maxValue or minValue parts out and just leaving one of them, but when I try to find both of them it gives me the error. I am pretty sure I need a while loop but I don't know how to construct it. I've tried count and stuff but that didn't work or continued to give me the same error. I'm pretty stumped.

```
def rangeOfValuesInFile(fileName):
    file = open(fileName)
    for ele in file:
        maxValue = max(file)
        minValue = min(file)    
        rangeValue = maxValue - minValue
        return maxValue.rstrip("\n"), minValue.rstrip("\n"), rangeValue.rstrip("\n")
    #Close the file.
    file.close()
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop. your return stop the for loop. you do max and min with the "file" not the "ele".

Comment: Check the solution provided on this link, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066207/find-minimum-maximum-and-average-value-of-a-text-file